# linq select statement vs direct access

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have two classes

```
class Supervisor
{
    public int SupervisorID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Trunk> Trunks { get; set; }

    //constructor + other code etc...//
}

class Trunk
{
    public int TrunkID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int SupervisorID { get; set; }

    //constructor + other code etc...//
}
```

The database these classes are connected to is full of data, **with at least one Trunk record for every Supervisor record.**

My question is this: 
Why does this code work correctly and print out the Trunk Name for each Supervisor:

```
//Works
var s = from x in db.Supervisors
        select x.Trunks.FirstOrDefault().Name;
foreach (var name in s)
    Console.WriteLine(name);
```

But this code does not and throws an ArgumentNullException?

```
//Doesn't Work: ArgumentNullException
foreach (var supervisor in db.Supervisors)
    Console.WriteLine(supervisor.Trunks.FirstOrDefault().Name);
```

Additionally, this code runs fine:

```
foreach (var supervisor in db.Supervisors)
    Console.WriteLine(supervisor.Name);
```

So it's only when accessing supervisor.Trunks that I'm getting null in the second code block.

Screenshot of the Supervisors table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8Ha6.jpg

Are these two code blocks not doing the exact same thing?

Comment: You're getting the error because `FirstOrDefault()` can return null, and you can get a property on a value that is null.

Comment: @ErikPhilips: The question is not why does that error occur but why does it occur on the second code and not the first which is at a glance doing the same thing (ie also has `FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: The clue is in the FirstOrDefault() - if Supervisor.Trunks is empty, you get back null. LINQ doesn't select anything for that Supervisor so there's no null in s. The simple foreach does not.

Comment: @Chris knowing why the error exists should help future users understand why this is happening.  I was attempting to lead the OP to the answer.

Comment: @NeilHewitt That would depend on the provider - LINQ on objects would produce an exception in both cases.

Comment: @NeilHewitt: if Supervisor.Trunks is empty then I would expect `FirstOrDefault` will return null in the first one too and thus give a null reference exception. Linq wouldn't generally be expected to ignore a value being selected because there is a null burried in the expression.

Comment: Yes, of course. But maybe EF doesn't. I have zero EF experience, admittedly, but it's the obvious answer if that's what the OP is seeing. I suspect I'm not helping so I'll bow out :-)

Comment: @paqogomez consider me appropriately shamefaced. Long day, thinking impaired.

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but I have to ask: Is db null in the second code example?  Which item is null in the second code example?  Have you verified whether FirstOrDefault() is returning null, or is it one of the other variables?

Comment: I may be totally wrong here but I just want to make a point. In working code we are asking to load Name on db.Supervisors where db is object context and that has enough information to perform easy load when asked. But this not the case with supervisor because supervisor does not contain information to load Name and supervisor is just a member of collection returned by db.Supervisors and hence throwing error.

Comment: I edited the question. @JMarsch `supervisors.Trunks` is `null` in the second code block. `FirstOrDefault()` is throwing the exception.

Comment: @NeilHewitt `Supervisor.Trunks`, in this case should never be empty. There is a least one Trunk record for each Supervisor.

Comment: @JoeBauer if `Supervisor.Trunks` is empty, and you are sure that you have at least one `Trunk` record for each `Supervisor` in the database, then something else is wrong. Did you run SQL Server Profiler to see what SQL is actually getting passed in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code:

```
var s = from x in db.Supervisors
    select x.Trunks.FirstOrDefault().Name;
```

is not actually executed as C# code.  This is compiling a series of `Expression` objects that define what the source code of this looks like.  It is not compiled into executable bytes.  Those `Expression` objects are then passed to a query provider, which translates the C# *source code* (or at least an equivalent) into SQL code, and runs that against the database.  That query provider can see that you're accessing the `Trunks` property of the object, it knows to transform that into a `Join`.  It sees that you're accessing the `Name` property of that table, so that's the column it selects out, etc.

When you write the following:

```
foreach (var supervisor in db.Supervisors)
```

Nothing is sent to the database except to pull back the entire `Supervisors` table.  It's not building up any `Expression` objects to define what the query might be.  There is no `Join` against the `Trunks` table.  The trunk name is not pulled out in the selector.

This related table is not eagerly loaded.  It is not going to populate the `supervisor` object with all of the `Trunks` information in the event that you might want to use it later.  That's just too expensive to do when objects have lots of relationships.  Since it's not populated at all, it'll be `null`, even if there are in fact `Trunk` objects in the database.

To tell the query provider, "Hey, I'm going to need the information from the Trunks table for these supervisors." You use the `Include` method:

```
foreach (var supervisor in db.Supervisors.Include(s => s.Trunks))
```

Of course, this is still inferior to your first solution because now you're pulling back all of the field from both tables, instead of just the trunk names.  That's a lot of wasted network traffic.

Yet another option is to [enable lazy initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23502701/1159478) of related entities.  This means that when you try to access a related entity that wasn't populated in a query it goes and does yet another round trip to the database to go and get that information, right when you need it.  In certain situations that can be fine, but here you *know* that you're going to need that information.  Performing an extra database round trip for every single supervisor is something you really want to avoid.  So this will result in your program working, instead of crashing, at the cost of being *much* slower than any other alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Your first expression:

```
var s = from x in db.Supervisors
        select x.Trunks.FirstOrDefault().Name;
```

results in an `IEnumerable<string>` whose values are the results of this query:

```
SELECT (
    SELECT [t2].[Name]
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (1) [t1].[Name]
        FROM [Trunk] AS [t1]
        WHERE [t1].[SupervisorId] = [t0].[SupervisorId]
        ) AS [t2]
    ) AS [value]
FROM [Supervisor] AS [t0]
```

If there are any instances of Supervisors that do not have any Trunks, a NULL value is returned for that record.

In the second expression

```
foreach (var supervisor in db.Supervisors)
    Console.WriteLine(supervisor.Trunks.FirstOrDefault().Name);
```

you are looping through the actual data structures on the client side. In this instance, if there are any Supervisors that do not have any Trunks, then you are trying to access the Name property of a null - that is where the ArgumentNullException is thrown.

My guess is you do have Supervisors that do not have any Trunks. Try changing that first query to the following and see if you return any records:

```
var s = from x in db.Supervisors
        select x.Trunks.FirstOrDefault().Name;
if(s.Any(name => name == null))
        Console.WriteLine("Trunkless supervisors detected.");
```

Comment: I ran your code and the writeline was never run. There are no null Names. I added a screenshot of the Supervisors table in the original question.

Comment: You get somewhat close to the answer here.  This *is* related to the fact that the first code snippet is translated into SQL code and the second is not, however it doesn't mean that there are no trunks for some supervisor.  As my answer explains, the issue is that because the second query isn't translated into SQL, the information isn't fetched at all, **even if that data is in the database**.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if there were not trunks for a supervisor, but that property were actually populated from the database, it would represent an empty collection, not a `null` collection, and `FirstOrDefault` wouldn't fail, it would just return `null`, and you'd get a NRE when trying to get the `Name` of `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled set to false..
this will not load related entities and will throw an error

Comment: As my answer explains in detail, this is related to what's going on.  The related entities are not being lazily loaded.  Of course, in this case he really *shouldn't* be lazily loading the entities.  He doesn't want to be executing an extra DB round trip for every single supervisor.  He should be pulling back the related information in the initial query instead.